two_dimensional_scrollables crashes when scrolling too fast with mousewheel
For my Flutter project i switched recently to two_dimmensional_scrollables and ditched my solution wih two scrollviews. The performance with this Widget is much better due to lazy loading.
Around the TableView.builder() Widget is use a ScrollConfiguration with a CustomScollbehaviour as parent to be able to scroll by dragging with mouse instead only to drag with touch.
I divided my TableView into smaller pieces to make use of the lazy loading.
Now i have the problem, that when scrolling fast enough with a mousewheel, due to faster scrollspeed or by showing more elements at the same time and scrolling slightly slower, the widget crashes and start to disappear when i continue scrolling. I get the following errors. Even a hot restart of the application doesn't recover the programm. I have to stop and restart the programm from scratch.
The problem does not appear when scrolling with any device using drag and drop, even for mouse Inputs.
What i tried:
I tried to invstigate the problem. The problem appears especially on devices with lower compute power. It also get worse, when the small pieces of the TableView need some calculation to build. I made the problem less worse by caching the already build widgets instead of rebuilding them when returning to an already visited spot in the Tableview.
Problem appears on the following Platforms: Web, Windows, Linux. For Android the problem not yet appeared, because there we were scrolling by touch and not with a mousewheel.
We were now at the current latest Version 0.2.1 with Flutter 3.19.5
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 783 pos 12: '_children.containsValue(child)': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TableView TableView:file:///home/<etc>/<etc>/file.dart:1131:40
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.parentDataOf (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:783:12)
#3      RenderTableViewport.parentDataOf (package:two_dimensional_scrollables/src/table_view/table.dart:395:13)
#4      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1264:17)
#5      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:451:13)
#6      Iterable.isEmpty (dart:core/iterable.dart:540:33)
#7      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1265:10)
#8      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:59)
#9      PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1097:15)
#10     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:14)
#11     RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1258:5)
#12     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2414:7)
#13     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1051:18)
#14     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1064:15)
#15     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:582:23)
#16     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:991:13)
#17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:448:5)
#18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1311:9)
#20     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#21     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#22     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#23     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderTableViewport#a1771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=2133.3, h=919.2)
...  layer: OffsetLayer#1f62a
...    engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#b03e9
...    handles: 2
...    offset: Offset(213.3, 356.9)
...  size: Size(2133.3, 919.2)
RenderObject: RenderTableViewport#a1771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=2133.3, h=919.2)
  layer: OffsetLayer#1f62a
    engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#b03e9
    handles: 2
    offset: Offset(213.3, 356.9)
size: Size(2133.3, 919.2)
...  (row: 0, column: 0): RenderRepaintBoundary#b39ec
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: vicinity=(row: 0, column: 0); layoutOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); visible - paintExtent=Size(610.0, 150.0); 
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=610.0, h=150.0)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#f7b0b
...      engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#89d12
...      handles: 2
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: Size(610.0, 150.0)
...    metrics: 97.0% useful (1 bad vs 32 good)
...    diagnosis: this is an outstandingly useful repaint boundary and should definitely be kept
...    child: RenderFlex#80fea
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=610.0, h=150.0)
...      size: Size(610.0, 150.0)
...      direction: horizontal
...      mainAxisAlignment: start
...      mainAxisSize: max
...      crossAxisAlignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      verticalDirection: down
...      child 1: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#94584 relayoutBoundary=up1
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 4.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=150.0)
...        semantics node: SemanticsNode#148
...          Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 4.0, 306.0, 146.0)
...          label: "Gesamt

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 783 pos 12: '_children.containsValue(child)': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TableView TableView:file:///home/<etc>/<etc>/file.dart:1131:40
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.parentDataOf (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:783:12)
#3      RenderTableViewport.parentDataOf (package:two_dimensional_scrollables/src/table_view/table.dart:395:13)
#4      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1264:17)
#5      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:451:13)
#6      Iterable.isEmpty (dart:core/iterable.dart:540:33)
#7      RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1265:10)
#8      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:59)
#9      PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1097:15)
#10     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:14)
#11     RenderTwoDimensionalViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/two_dimensional_viewport.dart:1258:5)
#12     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2414:7)
#13     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1051:18)
#14     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1064:15)
#15     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:582:23)
#16     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:991:13)
#17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:448:5)
#18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1311:9)
#20     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#21     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#22     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#23     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderTableViewport#a1771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=2133.3, h=919.2)
...  layer: OffsetLayer#1f62a
...    engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#278ca
...    handles: 2
...    offset: Offset(213.3, 356.9)
...  size: Size(2133.3, 919.2)
RenderObject: RenderTableViewport#a1771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=2133.3, h=919.2)
  layer: OffsetLayer#1f62a
    engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#278ca
    handles: 2
    offset: Offset(213.3, 356.9)
  size: Size(2133.3, 919.2)
...  (row: 0, column: 0): RenderRepaintBoundary#b39ec
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: vicinity=(row: 0, column: 0); layoutOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); visible - paintExtent=Size(610.0, 150.0); 
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=610.0, h=150.0)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#f7b0b
...      engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#89d12
...      handles: 2
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: Size(610.0, 150.0)
...    metrics: 97.1% useful (1 bad vs 33 good)
...    diagnosis: this is an outstandingly useful repaint boundary and should definitely be kept
...    child: RenderFlex#80fea
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=610.0, h=150.0)
...      size: Size(610.0, 150.0)
...      direction: horizontal
...      mainAxisAlignment: start
...      mainAxisSize: max
...      crossAxisAlignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      verticalDirection: down
...      child 1: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#94584 relayoutBoundary=up1
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 4.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=150.0)
...        semantics node: SemanticsNode#148
...          STALE
...          owner: null
...          Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 4.0, 306.0, 146.0)
...          label: "Gesamt
Gesamt
Gesamt
Projekte: 59
Projekte: 59



maybe you should post this problem on their GitHub issue
